# JDBC Query Caching and Precaching

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, orm, mybatis

### Scenario:

I have a need to cache the results of database queries in my web service. There about 30 tables queried during the cycle of a service call. I am confident data in a certain date range will be accessed frequently by the service, and I would like to pre-cache that data. This would mean caching around 800,000 rows at application startup, the data is read-only. The data does not need to be dynamically refreshed, this is reference data. The cache can't be loaded on each service call, there's simply too much data for that. Data outside of this 'frequently used' window is not time critical and can be lazy loaded. Most queries would return 1 row, and none of the tables have a parent/child relationship to each other, though there will be a few joins. There is no need for dynamic sql support.

### Options:

I intended to use myBatis, but there isn't a good method to warm up the cache. myBatis can't understand that the service query `select * from table where key = ?` is already covered by the startup pre-cache query `select * from table`.

As far as I understand it (documentation overload), Hibernate has the same problem. Additionally, these tables were designed with composite keys and no primary key, which is an extra hassle for Hibernate.

### Question:

Preferred: Is there a myBatis solution for this problem ? I'd very much like to use it. (Familiarity, simplicity, performance, funny name, etc)

Alternatively: Is there an ORM or DB-friendly cache that offers what I'm looking for ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use distributed caching solution like [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) or [Tayzgrid](http://www.alachisoft.com/tayzgrid/) which provide indexing and queries features along with cache startup loader.

You can configure indexes on attributes of your entities in cache. A [cache startup loader](http://www.alachisoft.com/support/support_articles/how-to-use-cache-startup-loader.html) can be configured to load all data from database in cache at cache startup. While loading data, cache will create indexes for all entities in memory.

[Object Query Language (OQL)](http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/articles/cache-parallel-query.html) feature, which provides queries similar to SQL can then be used to query in-memory data.

Answer (score 0):

The variety of options for third-party products (free and paid) is too broad and too dependent on your particular requirements and operational capabilities to try to "answer" here.

However, I will suggest an alternative to an explicit cache of your read-only data.

You clearly believe that the memory footprint of your dataset will fit into RAM on a reasonably-sized server. My suggestion is that you use your database engine directly (no additional external cache), but configured the database with internal cache large enough to hold your whole dataset. If all of your data is residing in the database server's RAM, it will be accessed very quickly.

I have used this technique successfully with mySQL, but I expect the same applies to all major database engines. If you cannot figure out how to configure your chosen database appropriately, I suggest that you follow ask a separate, detailed question.

You can warm the cache by executing representative queries when you start your system. These queries will be relatively slow because they have to actually do the disk I/O to pull the relevant blocks of data into the cache. Subsequent queries that access the same blocks of data will be much faster.

This approach should give you a huge performance boost with no additional complexity in your code or your operational environment.

Answer (score 0):

[Sormula](http://www.sormula.org) may do want you want. You would need to annotate each POJO to be cached like:

```
@Cached(type=ReadOnlyCache.class)
public class SomePojo {
...
}
```

Pre-populate the cache by invoking selectAll method for each:

```
Database db = new Database(one of the JNDI constructors);
Table<SomePojo> t = db.getTable(SomePojo.class);
t.selectAll();
```

The key is that the cache is stored in the Table object, t. So you would need to keep a reference to t and use it for subsequent queries. Or in the case of many tables, keep reference to database object, db, and use db.getTable(...) to get tables to query.

See [javadoc](http://www.sormula.org/javadoc/org/sormula/annotation/cache/Cached.html) and tests in org.sormula.tests.cache.readonly package.